# Debugging Perl variable interpolation

Tags: perl

I have a problem with my variable setup. Part of this command is working, except the `awk` command. Is it the use of `$2` in this case?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd = qx(df -h | awk '{print $2}');
print "Output:$cmd\n";
```

Comment: What do you get when you run it, and what do you expect to get?

Comment: @Igor With that code, he should be getting `Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string`.

Comment: Yes, I was a little slow on that one. I answered 3 minutes after you, but my answer was exactly the same as yours, so I deleted mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$2` is evaluated by perl into a variable. You need to escape it:

```
my $cmd = qx(df -h | awk '{print \$2}');
```

Update:

You may wish to check out [Filesys::DiskSpace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys%3a%3aDiskSpace). Using perl native solutions is most often better than trying to use system calls and parsing input.

Comment: In general you can make qx (or m, s, or qr) be non-interpolating by using ' as the delimiter, but in this case then you'd have to escape the quotes to awk's arg: `qx'df -h | awk \'{print $2}\''`